# Entityframework ID not set

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following Objects in my project. The "Gast"-Object can have many "Aufenthalt"-Objects and the "Aufenthalt"-Object can have many "Mitreisender"-Object. Every "Mitreisender" can be assigned to only one "Aufenthalt" and every "Aufenthalt" can be assigned to only one Gast.

When i click Button2 then everything works but only the ID for the "Gast" is null in the Aufenthalt..

```
public class Gast
{
    public int GastID { get; set; }
    public string Anrede { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Aufenthalt> Aufenthalte {get; set;}

    public Gast()
    {
        Aufenthalte = new List<Aufenthalt>();
    }
}

public class Mitreisender
{
    public int MitreisenderID { get; set; }
    public string Anrede { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Geburtstag { get; set; }

    public virtual Aufenthalt Aufenthalt { get; set; }
}

public class Aufenthalt
{
    public int AufenthaltID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Anreisedatum { get; set; }
    public DateTime Abreisedatum { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Mitreisender> Mitreisende { get; set; }

    public virtual Gast Gast { get; set; }

    public Aufenthalt()
    {
        Mitreisende = new List<Mitreisender>();
    }
}
```

my dbcontext

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
class GastContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Gast> Gaeste { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Aufenthalt> Aufenthalte { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mitreisender> Mitreisende { get; set; }
}
```

my button

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new GastContext())
        {
            Aufenthalt aufenthalt = new Aufenthalt();
            aufenthalt.Anreisedatum = dtp_aufenthalt_anreise.Value;
            aufenthalt.Abreisedatum = dtp_aufenthalt_abreise.Value;

            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv_aufenthalt_mitreisende.Items)
            {
                Mitreisender m = new Mitreisender
                {
                    Anrede = lvi.SubItems[0].Text,
                    Vorname = lvi.SubItems[1].Text,
                    Nachname = lvi.SubItems[2].Text
                };

                db.Mitreisende.Add(m);
                aufenthalt.Mitreisende.Add(m);
            }

            currentGast.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);
            db.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);

            db.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Aufenthalt wurde angelegt");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is `currentGast` getting its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currentGast is not tracked by the context, because you have created a new context in the event handler.

Delete this code:

```
currentGast.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);
db.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Replace it to this code:

```
var cg = db.Gaste.Single(x => x.GastID == currentGast.GastID );
cg.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jannagy02's answer: you could also attach `currentGast` to the context.  So, instead of

```
currentGast.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);
db.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);

db.SaveChanges();
```

You'd have

```
db.Gaste.Attach(currentGast);
currentGast.Aufenthalte.Add(aufenthalt);

db.SaveChanges();
```

As janagy02 notes below: this will only work if `currentGast` is not already attached to another `DbContext`.  However, in that case I would note that having multiple open `DbContext`s (attached to the same database) within the same application response-context is not a practice I would recommend.

Comment: Yes, but because we do not see all the code, it could be that currentGast is already attached to another instance of the context, and then there is an exception.